# How can I resolve this React Modal Problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-modal

I am using react and I am a beginner in React. I am facing a problem while using React Modal.
It looks like modal is working but something is stopping it from working when I click on the button which opens Modal then this happens => The screen just blinks , The Modal opens and closes suddenly. I am using `React useState Hook`. No errors are reflected by the compiler in this code.

Here is my code :

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal'
import '../CSS/LoginSignup.css'
const LoginSignup = () => {
    const [modalIsOpen , setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    function openModal() {
        setIsOpen(true);
      }
    function closeModal() {
        setIsOpen(false);
    }
    function afterOpenModal() {
        if(!closeModal){
            setIsOpen(true);
        }
      }
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <div className="mainContainer">
                    <div className="maincontrol">
                        <div className="tagline">
                            <h1>Chat Free</h1>
                            <span><p>Connect with peoples and chat the way you like.</p></span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="login">
                            <form className="form">
                                <input type="text" id="login" className="inp1" name="login" placeholder="Email address or phone number" />
                                <input id="password" type="password" className="inp1" name="login" placeholder="Password" />
                                <button type="submit" className="btn" value="Log In">Log In</button>
                                <a href="">Forgotten password?</a>
                                <button type="SignUp" className="btn1" value="Sign Up" name="signUp" onClick={openModal}>Sign Up</button>
                                <Modal isOpen={modalIsOpen}
                                    onAfterOpen={afterOpenModal}
                                    onRequestClose={closeModal}
                                >
                                    <div className="modal">
                                        <div className="modal-content">
                                            <h2>Sign Up!</h2>
                                            <span className="close" onClick={closeModal} >&times;</span>
                                            <form className='formsignup'>
                                                <div className="fullname">
                                                    <div className="firtname">
                                                        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="firstname" />
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="surname">
                                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="lastname" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="emailphone">
                                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email or phone number" id="ephone"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="password">
                                                    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" id="password"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="dobmain">
                                                    <div className="date">
                                                        <label htmlFor="dob">Date of birth</label>
                                                        <input type="number" placeholder="Date" id="date"/>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="month">
                                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Month" id="month"/>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="year">
                                                        <input type="number" placeholder="Year" id="year"/>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="gender">
                                                    <div className="male">
                                                        <label htmlFor="">Male</label>
                                                        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" />
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="female">
                                                        <label htmlFor="">Female</label>
                                                        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" />
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="other">
                                                        <label htmlFor="">Other</label>
                                                        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="button">
                                                    <button type="Register" className="btnR" value="Register" name="register">Sign Up</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </Modal>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </>
    )
}

export default LoginSignup
```

It is the content on my console:

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
webpackHotDevClient.js:138 src\Component\LoginSignup.js
  Line 33:33:  The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
printWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:138
```

Comment: Can you explain what the stuff inside `afterOpenModal()` is supposed to do?

Comment: It is supposed to open the modal unit and unless someone clicks on Close button. I made it to resolve the open close problem but it didn't worked.

Comment: The function content makes no sense. `if(!closeModal){`? That's a function, not a variable. And why set it to open again in a function that is called after it opens?

Comment: check the `href` and it has clearly mentioned to use a button and change ..... if we cannot provide a valid href

Comment: I thought this will resolve the problem. @ChrisG

Comment: @Codenewbie I didn't get you. Which `href` you are talking about?

Comment: I think it is not connected to `Modal` at all. Please try to insert `href="javascript:;"` in your line 33. I am talking about this:  ` <a href="">Forgotten password?</a>`

Comment: It is connected I am Damn sure because when I hit the sign up button. The modal pops up but unfortunately it closes immediately.

Comment: try to Change click function `onClick={ () => openModal()}`

Comment: The problem here is that the signup button is inside the form, which means clicking the button will also submit the form. Use `type="button"` for the signup button and this won't happen. However you should probably reorganize your <form> tags / split them up (or even remove them).

Comment: @ChrisG Let me try . I am supposed to write this `type="button"` ?

Comment: Answer this instead of comment I will make that a correct one for this issue.

Comment: This is a well known issue unrelated to React that definitely has an existing answer. I'm too lazy to search for the duplicate though.